# Showing that $\mathbb{Z_p^*}$ is closed under multiplication.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Let p be a prime and let $\mathbb{Z_p^*} = \{1,2\cdot\cdot\cdot p-1\}$.
Let $x,y \in \mathbb{Z_p^*}$. Is the following correct:

Since $x \neq 0$ mod $p$ and $y \neq 0$ mod $p \to xy \neq 0$ mod $p \to \mathbb{Z_p^*}$ is closed under multiplication?

Comment: You're probably supposed to note that since p is prime, it divides a product of two numbers iff it divides one of them.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I was just wondering if that modular argument was correct.

Comment: Would you have to prove that $\Bbb Z_p$ has no non-trivial zero divisors?

Comment: @Mathaniel: that very much depends on how you define things and what are your established facts. When proving things this low-level, you have to be careful to avoid circularity.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. The method described in your initial approach is clearly the way to go.